# How do I deal with a colleague who is behaving irrationally?

Tags: india

This is getting serious. This senior colleague has lost his mental sanity. Or he just wants to get sacked and get the compensation. He is so weird. He keeps poking at me for no reason. Tries to put me down, tries to trigger me etc. But sometimes acts like he's very close to me. I can't ignore him because he comes to me, I don't go to him. But I'm starting to get scared of this. Everyone in our department is aware of this, but surprisingly, nobody has taken any action. I mean they should help and support me or do something.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: It's almost like teams have managers to give guidance on things.

Comment: Does he physically poke you ? Or does he only try to use words to irritate, harass, put you down in order to provoke you, and to get a strong and bad reaction from you (so that HR can fire him)?

Comment: "**...sometimes act like he's very near to me...**" What does that mean ? Does that mean he tries to be nice to you ?

Comment: Does he treat everyone the same way ? Or does he only pick on you for some reason ?

Comment: i forgot to tell he is insane with everyone.

Comment: Yes he tries to act nicer. @Job_September_2020. No he doesn't do anything physically.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a few things in this order:

1. Talk to that senior coworker, and explain to him that you do
   not like what he does to you.
2. If that does not work, talk to your manager.
3. If that does not work, talk to HR.

Answer (score 2):

I would be VERY cautious about using the word "insane" or anything similar.  You are (I assume) NOT a psychologist or psychiatrist and have this person under your care.  Therefore you are unqualified to render such a diagnosis and open yourself up to potential issues if you make such declarations to others.

Focus on the actual behaviors that you find unacceptable and keep track of them in writing so that you can refer to them later.  Keep track of what exactly he did and how it affected you.

Raise a formal complaint with your company's HR dept. using the procedures in place for this.  If the coworker is touching you or otherwise harassing you then that is almost certainly against company policy and likely illegal.

You, however, want to do everything BY THE BOOK in order to protect your own interests here.